# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ... Controller#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following line in my news_lists_controller.rb file is generating an error:

```
(1 .. @tot_actions).each do |a|
      NewsAction.create(:status_id => @action_status_id[a], :user_id => @action_user_id[a], :email_change => @email_changed[a] )
end
```

The database field `:email_change` is a boolean field. I set @email_changed[a] to `true` and `false` values and got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in News listsController#index
```

When i set it to 0 and 1 I received the same error. There are no attr_accessible in the model. news_action.rb contents:

```
class NewsAction < Field
end
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: For those who might might make the same mistake i did, check out my comment below for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any `attr_accessible` defined in your model?

If so, you may need to add `:email_change` to the list

Comment: +1 for trying. Actually it was a stupid mistake. I should have had < ActiveRecord::Base instead of < Field. That's what i get for taking a shortcut by copying and pasting other code without thinking' :=]